# how to recording pause in android

Tags: record, recording, mediarecorder

i am developing an application in android to record voice will generate a mp3 file,but my problem is to pause while  recording with Android MediaRecorder class.
Can any body help me?
Any kind of help appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Android SDK doesn't provide such functionality out of the box. You have the following options:

1. Use `AudioRecord` class from Android SDK, which is more low-level than `MediaRecord` and outputs uncompressed PCM data as a byte stream. Raw PCM data can be compressed using `android.media.AmrInputStream` (not part of the official API). There are some problems with this approach - `AmrInputStream` only supports 8 kHz sampling rate, so quality is not the best, though reasonable.
2. If you need the best quality possible and guaranteed support on all devices, record muptiple files using `MediaRecord` class from Android SDK and merge them using 3rd-party native library such as `ffmpeg`. This will be difficult (you will have to use NDK and write wrapper program in C).

Comment: Deville I have used the ffmpeg and it stucks while merging. It throws exception check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595508/java-io-ioexception-cannot-append-mp4trackimplhandler-vide-to-mp4trackimpl