# java.io.IOException: Cannot append Mp4TrackImpl{handler='vide'} to Mp4TrackImpl{handler='vide'} since their Sample Description Boxes differ:

Tags: android, ffmpeg, append, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

While Merging the multiple videos using ffmpeg I have got this Exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot append Mp4TrackImpl{handler='vide'} to Mp4TrackImpl{handler='vide'} since their Sample Description Boxes differ:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be you are using, convert your video in MPEG4. Use H264 format for set the video codec

Change this

recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);

to this

recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

Comment: Yeah it works Thanksalot but still I need to use the MPEG4 codec.

Comment: @Arslan, did you ever figure out how to then convert from H264 to the needed MPEG4? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: Does it take too long to convert the file in this format ? Its taking too long for me and the issue is also not solved !!

Comment: Can you please share the other parameters of the recorder ? I am trying using the same encoding but it doesn't merge and says the same error.

Comment: Hi Aly can you please elaborate your answer. i would really be helpful